# Code works in jsfiddle but doesn't work when I put all the code into my website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to have a button on each side of my iframe (which contains a calendar) which toggles back and forth between calendar #1 and calendar #2 in a single iframe.

Any suggestions?

```
|arrowLeft| |-----Iframe-------| |arrowRight|
```

The code works in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PauWy/447/) but doesn't work when I put all the code into my website.

Why is that?

```
HTML:

<p id="toggle">
<span> Left </span>
<span> </span>
</p>

<div id="left"> <iframe>LEFT CONTENT</iframe> L</div>
<div id="right"> <iframe>RIGHT CONTENT</iframe>R </div>

<p id="toggle">
<span></span>
<span> Right </span></p>
```

CSS:

```
#right { display:none; }
```

Script:

```
$('#toggle > span').click(function() {
   var ix = $(this).index();

   $('#left').toggle( ix === 0 );
   $('#right').toggle( ix === 1 );
});
```

Comment: Might be a stupid question but are you loading the jQuery script itself? Since you didn't post your entire code, it's hard to say ;-)

Comment: Wow, isn't this the third time you ask the exact same question today? What is wrong with all other answers you got in your duplicates?

Comment: yes it is, but no-one has given me a solution. so i will post it 100000 times untill i get a good answer. thanks for your unnecessary  complaining :)

Comment: Fred- yes i have ':/ i dunno why it isnt working for me, i have all the code in the proper places, have the 1.9.1 jQuery script linked,

Comment: you are welcome :) But it might help (you as a new user) to know that asking the same question '100000 times untill you get a good answer' is at best 'frowned upon' on SO..

Comment: I suggest that you find a `working toggle` script out there and test it with what you have now and some of the answers that have been given to you. Watch for duplicate calls. There are literally thousands out there; trial & error works and is a very good way to learn. One who never made a mistake hasn't learned a single thing ;-)

Comment: well i entered the code up above in jsfeddle and it works on there, so im going crazy wondering why it wont work on my site :(

Comment: @user2220051 it might be a jQuery `version` issue itself. It's happened to me before where a certain version of it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Fred, that jsfiddle is set to version 1.9.1 and the asker stated in the above comments to have linked to 1.9.1, so that's probably not the problem.

Comment: PROBLEM IS SOLVED !!!!!!!!!! Thank you GitaarLAB <3

Comment: You should not assign more than one HTML element the same `id`.

Comment: @ErikE: you are absolutely right on that one. I updated my answer with that catch (crediting you), together with your suggestions in your comments to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you have loaded jquery..

Probably your onclick setter (the jquery code) is run before the document is loaded (and as such there are no elements in document.body at that moment to set).

In jsfiddle ('No-Library' pure JS) code is wrapped (by default) in:

```
window.onload=function(){
// your code here
};
```

That should already do the trick.

This is what jsfiddle does when you select the (default) option 'onLoad' in the options panel on the left, under "Frameworks & Extensions".

If you would select 'onDomready' then your code would (currently) be wrapped in a function called `VanillaRunOnDomReady`, like this:

```
var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() {
// your code here
}

var alreadyrunflag = 0;

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        alreadyrunflag=1; 
        VanillaRunOnDomReady();
    }, false);
else if (document.all && !window.opera) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" id="contentloadtag" defer="defer" src="javascript:void(0)"><\/script>');
    var contentloadtag = document.getElementById("contentloadtag")
    contentloadtag.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (this.readyState=="complete"){
            alreadyrunflag=1;
            VanillaRunOnDomReady();
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout("if (!alreadyrunflag){VanillaRunOnDomReady}", 0);
}
```

Note that this eventually *still* ends up in a `window.onload` like the 'onLoad' option.

If you'd load library JQuery 1.9.1 then things change (a little).
The option 'onLoad' then wraps your code like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
// your code here
});
```

Note that this is essentially still the the same as the first option in this answer, but then in the JQuery way.

If you'd select the option 'onDomready' (whilst the JQuery library is loaded in JSFiddle), then your code would be wrapped in:

```
$(function(){
// your code here
});
```

---

As ErikE pointed out in the comments below, since you already load and use JQuery you might also want to use yet another JQuery way:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// your code here
});
```

Finally as ErikE also pointed out in his comment to your question (a serious problem I overlooked), `id`'s are meant to be unique. Whereas you gave to both paragraphs the id "toggle".
You should instead give them the `class` "toggle" and select the elements by class to assign the onclick function.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that I took the liberty of changing the title of your question so it is clear that you where asking something different after all! Keep this in mind for future questions.

Comment: I would suggest `$(document).ready(function() { });` instead of `onload`.

Comment: @ErikE: That is indeed another option but then jquery wouldn't be optional anymore but a dependency. So I chose to explain *why* the code worked in jsfiddle and *not* on his site (hoping it would be of better future use for other people, together with the updated title). And this is how jsfiddle does it by default (as can be seen by right-clicking the output-window and viewing the source).

Comment: He's already using jQuery so there's nothing optional about it... ??? And about `ready` vs. `onload`, that's just an option in jsFiddle: in the options panel on the left, under "Frameworks & Extensions", change the dropdown from "onLoad" to "onDomready".

Comment: @ErikE: so now thanks to your comment, future readers will know that to, together with an explanation what jsfiddle did by default. Isn't SO great? (Trying not to repeat my previous comment). If it would make you happy, I could *add* the jquery way to my answer?

Comment: Fair enough! Well played. :)

Comment: Thx :) I just try to be an asset to the community (like the dino I'm becoming). (hoping that works both way's, unlike EE).

Comment: Just a note: there are pretty much two primary benefits of using `ready` in jQuery: 1. The event can run *before* the `load` event--which can be a real issue when there are loaded resources such as images. `load` only fires after the images are done loading, but the user can interact with the page before then. So `ready` lets your script run as soon as the DOM can be manipulated, so the user doesn't have weird things happening or expected things not happening. 2. All the really hard cross-browser stuff to successfully accomplish #1 has already been done for you.

Comment: @ErikE: That is a great addon, plus 1 (to get it in the short relevant comment list).